# Что быстрее map.containsKey(key) || map.get(key) != null

Tags: java, map

К примеру мне нужно проверить, существует ли какие-либо данные в `map`, если существуют, то вернуть иначе загрузить из базы данных.

```
    Map<String, Data> map = Maps.newHashMap();

    //Вариант 1
    map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) : map.put(key, loadFromDatabase(key));

    //Вариант 2
    Data data = map.get(key);

    if (data == null) {
        data = map.put(key, loadFormDatabase(key));
    }

    return data;
```

Т.е. вопрос в том, что будет быстрей: предварительная проверка на существование ключа в `map`, прежде чем делать `get` или же сразу `get` и проверка на `!= null`

Comment: прошу прощение а первый вариант - какой-то специфичный синтаксис? Сначала  показалась, что тернарка. А теперь смотрю - нет

Comment: @СергейКуренчук да, ошибка там, поправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Быстрее, короче и нагляднее будет `map.computeIfAbsent(key, SomeClass::loadFromDatabase)`

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, что второе быстрее, поскольку оно содержит на одно действие (вызов `containsKey`) меньше. С другой стороны, стоит обратить внимание на то, могут ли в словаре находиться значения `null`. Если да, то второй код будет постоянно лазить за ними в базу, а первый отработает верно.